# .next selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code.

```js
$( function() {
var premium1 = $( "#premium1" ).spinner({
      change: function( event, ui ) {
       if($( "#premium1" ).spinner( "value" )!=0){
       CountGroupOne(this.id);
       }
       else
       {
        ShowAll(1);
       }
       
      }
    });
  });
function CountGroupOne(id){
   alert(id);
   var price=$("#"+id).nextAll('input:first').val();
   alert(price);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="premium1" type="number" name="premium[1][1][]" value="0" min='0' max='30'/><input type="number" hidden name="price[]" value="2"/>
```

When I get the `id` the alert is give me back,but the `alert2` give me `undefined` . Whats the problem? The HTML simple two `input`.

Comment: Provide HTML code also.

Comment: Yes getting the corret ID and the html is the exact code.

Comment: Check generated code. JQuery UI produces new HTML - and you can't get next input on this way...

Comment: I think the spinner plugin is wrapping the input with some element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
function CountGroupOne(id){
    alert(id);
    var price=$("#"+id).parent().next('input').val();
    alert(price);
  }
```

JQuery UI Spinner produces span, and your first input is wrapped in span...

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/54naesgp/

P.S. Always use developer tools, and inspect generated html.

Comment: Np, glad to help. ;)